# CAS gives me a weird answer for simple rational integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral
$$\int \frac{x^8dx}{x^3+x^2+2}$$
Does not seem to be solvable by most CAS's. This was tested on Maple and WolframAlpha and the result returned is

[image: Result]

What is the weird summation doing at the right of the integral? The answer in the answer key is 
$$ \frac{x^6}6- \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{2x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2} + 4x + 3\ln(x+1) + \frac{11}{8}\ln(x^2-x+2)-\frac{171}{12\sqrt7}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)+C $$

Answer (score 1):

just a start

$$  \left(   x^{8}  \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  +  x^{2}  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  + 5 x  - 7 \right) } +  \left(  13 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 14 \right)  $$

Then $$    13 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 14 =  13 x^2 + \frac{26}{3} x - \frac{56}{3} x + 14   $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^3+x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, it is natural that trying to compute a primitive of $\frac{x^8}{x^3+x^2+2}$ will lead to a complex expression. And the function that you mention at the end of your question is *not* such a primitive, since its derivative is$$\frac{x^8+\frac{11}4x^2-\frac{11}4x+\frac{11}2}{x^3+x+1}.$$

Comment: I did not understand the word _irreducible_. Could you please explain that concept in more detail?

Comment: In the context of cubic polynomials with rational coefficients, it means that it has no rational root.